# SQL Query That Shows All Reps Even If No Sales (Records)

Tags: mysql, sql, crystal-reports

I have the following query that takes each sales reps, orders, # of pieces sold, and sales amount each day. It shows each day of the month, and within each day it shows all the reps who have had sales that day. The problem is, on a certain day, if  only half the reps made sales, it will only show those reps. I'd like it to show each day, and each rep even if they have not made sales. I know this normally should be a simple fix with the way the tables are joined, but I am having an issue figuring it out. I'm not sure if it has to do with the way I'm grouping things. Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
        mh.simh_kdate as "Date",
        ctls.sm_name AS "Sales Person Name",
        COUNT(DISTINCT md.simd_inv) as "Orders",
        SUM(CASE WHEN i.iv_current in ('0', '1') 
        THEN IF(mh.`simh_inv`<100000,-md.`simd1_shipped`,md.`simd1_shipped`) ELSE 0 END) as "Pieces",    
        SUM(md.`simd1_extended`) AS "Sales Amount"

FROM c_file c 
    LEFT JOIN simh_file mh on c.cm_custno = mh.simh_kcust
    LEFT JOIN simd_file md on md.simd_inv = mh.simh_inv AND md.simd_seq = mh.simh_seq
    LEFT JOIN ctl_file_s ctls on ctls.sm_slm = mh.simh__slm
    LEFT JOIN i_file i on i.iv_item = md.simd1_item
WHERE mh.simh_kdate between 20210701 and 20210731
Group by ctls.sm_name, mh.simh_kdate
order by mh.simh_kdate
```

The output is currently something like this:

```
| Date    | Name   | Orders| Pieces| Sales |
|:------- |:------:| -----:| -----:| -----:|
| 7/1/21  | Rep 1  | 1     |10     | 150.00|
| 7/1/21  | Rep 2  | 1     |5      | 24.99 |
| 7/1/21  | Rep 4  | 3     |15     | 178.95|
| 7/2/21  | Rep 1  | 2     |2      | 55.55 |
| 7/3/21  | Rep 3  | 1     |1      | 10.00 |
| 7/3/21  | Rep 6  | 1     |2      | 25.99 |
| 7/4/21  | Rep 2  | 4     |12     | 201.15|
```

But say I have 6 reps, I'd like 7/1/2021 to show reps 1 through 6 even if only reps 1,2 and 4 have sales. Ultimately I am using this query to create a cross tab report in crystal reports.

Comment: Left join your result to a list of reps of interest.

Comment: I have a left join on the table that contains all the reps, so I figured that should do the trick, but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I followed those guidelines. Is there a particular part of my question that you are confused about?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all reps, you need to start with the "reps" table and move filtering in other tables to the `on` clause.  I think this would be:

```
FROM ctl_file_s ctls LEFT JOIN
     simh_file mh
     ON ctls.sm_slm = mh.simh__slm AND
        mh.simh_kdate between 20210701 and 20210731 LEFT JOIN
     simd_file md
     ON md.simd_inv = mh.simh_inv AND md.simd_seq = mh.simh_seq LEFT JOIN
     c_file c
     ON c.cm_custno = mh.simh_kcust LEFT JOIN
     i_file i 
     ON i.iv_item = md.simd1_item
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it is still giving me the same result. I know normally that should work. But I guess they way I'm grouping things is maybe throwing it off?

Comment: @mf1124 . . . There should be no `where` clause -- and it should then return all rows in `ctls`.

Comment: So I can't use a where clause at all? I have to use at least a few. Even when I use a where clause for something like where reps in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) it will only show me 1 and 2 if they're the only ones with sales.

Comment: A `where` clause filtering on reps should be fine if the filter is on the table `ctls` (which I assumes is where the rep is located.

Comment: Yea they are located in ctls. But unfortunately it still only shows reps if they've made sales ironically.

Comment: @mf1124 . . . .Did you remove the `WHERE` clause?  The condition on `mh` should be *moved* to the `ON` clause (by which I intended that the condition not be in the `WHERE` clause).